# Inserting a date into a database

Tags: php, jquery

I have a project with a live table tied to a MySQL database.

I made a form that would take in the users input and insert into the database. But I'm having trouble inserting a date.

I used jQuery and Ajax to pass the values as a datastring to my PHP document that executes the insert query:

jQuery/Ajax:

```
$('.btn-add').click(function () {
        if ($('.add-form').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.add-form').slideDown(400);
            $(this).children('i').fadeOut(100);
        } else {
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var genres = $("#genres").val();
            var languages = $("#languages").val();
            var dev = $("#dev").val();
            var date = $(".picker").next().val().split(".").reverse().join("-");;
            // I used a date picker for this. It picks the date as "dd.mm.yyyy." 
            //and I had jquery convert it to "yyyy-mm-dd" for mysql compatibility.
            var dataString = 'title1=' + title + '&genres1=' + genres + '&languages1=' + languages + '&dev1=' + dev + '&date1=' + date;
            if (title == '' || genres == '' || languages == '' || dev == '' || date == '') {
                Materialize.toast('Please complete all the forms.', 4000);
            } else {
                // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/add-game.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        tableLoad();
                        Materialize.toast(result, 4000);
                        $('.add-form').slideUp(400);
                        $('.btn-add').children('i').fadeIn(100);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

add-game.php:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "****", "db-name");

    $title = $_POST["title1"];
    $genres = $_POST["genres1"];
    $languages = $_POST["languages1"];
    $dev = $_POST["dev1"];
    $date = $_POST["date1"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO games (title, genres, languages, developer, release-date) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$genres', '$languages','$dev','$date')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong.";
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Now, first I tried the code only passing the first 4 text values, without the date, and it worked just fine: the new row was added having the input info and the table refreshed, but I can't seem to get it to insert the date properly.

I tried echoing the `$date` with the error message inside the `.php` document, and it shows me the date in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format just fine. Yet still something goes wrong, and I can't tell what it is.

edit-1:

Here's the database structure:
[image]

edit-2:
The contents of the debug.txt file:

[image]

As you can see, the date format is just fine. (15th of March 2015)

Comment: Is the `release-date` field in your database a date field?? What is stored in the database? Or nothing at all.... can share your db structure as well?

Comment: Add a `file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($_POST,TRUE));` to the top of the code. Then look at `debug.txt` to see what is coming from your javascript code. Post that in your question with an edit.

Comment: can you please post date-picker initializing code and database table definition as well.

Comment: Or (as alternative), `print_r($_POST);` on the PHP page and `console.log(result);` in the success function. You can then see the output in the console.

Comment: its a bad idea to have a hyphen `-` separated column name.Should use an underscore `_` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's correct to me.
I would check if release-date column is really a DATE column.
And try to hardcode the date in the query, to see if it's an input problem or what.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO games (title, genres, languages, developer, release-date)
VALUES ('$title', '$genres', '$languages','$dev','2016-05-01')";
```

Edit:
I did some testing, it's because of the columnt name release-date, since it contains the '-' character. try changing the coulmn name to release_date or releasedate. else you could escape the column name in the query, but i would avoid this if you can, since it can lead to the same error the next time you have to build a query and it's not that easy to find out the error.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO games (title, genres, languages, developer, `release-date`) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$genres', '$languages','$dev','$date')"
```

notice that ` is diffent from '
i don't even have it on my keyboard.

Comment: I posted the database structure to show it is indeed a date column. Also tried hardcoding the date, and it still doesn't work, I'm starting to think the issue might be on the database side. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if it fixed the problem

Comment: @TeeSeal please try with the column name `release_date` instead of `release-date` once.Does it saves fine in that case?

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem. Don't know what MySQL's got with the "-" character, but I guess I'm gonna have to stick to underscores for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you in order to parse a String to a MySql Date format you can try the  MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() function:

```
"INSERT INTO games (title, genres, languages, developer, release-date) 
('$title', '$genres', '$languages','$dev',STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y'))";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change a few lines in `Ajax Call` And `PHP Code`. It will make your code clear and of course your problem will be solved.

**Ajax Call:**

```
data:{ "dataString":dataString},
```

**PHP Code:**

```
parse_str($_POST['dataString'],$data);

$title = $data["title1"];
$genres = $data["genres1"];
$languages = $data["languages1"];
$dev = $data["dev1"];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["date1"]));
```

And Then Run insert your query. It will work.